# Unable to refresh listview

Tags: android, listview

I am using customadapter to set data for list which contains a text view, imageview and a layout with some buttons. the buttons layout will be invisible initially. When we click on list item the layout has to appear with user able to click a button. This work fine as long as ImageView is static.

But our build will fetch image from url and set it to view. Here the refresh issue arises. The Layout is unable to be view.

List refreshes when re apply any external even such as Track ball or scroll.

Please help me regarding this.....

Answer (score 1):

Without actual code, it's hard to tell what the problem is, but have you tried calling `invalidate()` (inside UI thread) or `postInvalidate()` (outside UI thread) on the layout or any view you need to redraw? This forces the view to call `onDraw()` again.